# Android databinding on inner class not updating TextView

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, android-databinding

App runs but the `TextView` doesn't get update here is the relevant code.

activity_picker_dashboard.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Top header -->

    <include layout="@layout/layout_header" /> This layout has databinding

    <!-- DrawerLayout -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">
.....
```

Here is layout_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="profilePayload"
            type="myms.models.ProfileResponse.Payload"/>
    </data>

<Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_color"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@{profilePayload.firstName}" Here it is
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/role"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

...............
</Toolbar>
</layout>
```

Here is my model ProfileResponse.java

```
public class ProfileResponse
{
    public Payload getPayLoad() {
        return payLoad;
    }

    @SerializedName("Payload")
    private Payload payLoad;

    public static class Payload
    {
        public String getProfileId() {
            return profileId;
        }

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        @SerializedName("ProfileId")
        private String profileId;

        @SerializedName("UserId")
        private String userId;

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @SerializedName("FirstName")

        private String firstName;

        @SerializedName("LastName")
        private String lastName;
    }
}
```

And finally here is my activity

```
 public class PickerDashboardActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picker_dashboard);

        LayoutHeaderBinding binding = LayoutHeaderBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        ProfileResponse.Payload profilePayload = new ProfileResponse.Payload();
        profilePayload.setFirstName("Test");

        binding.setProfilePayload(profilePayload);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

Please suggest a solution. I have been trying this for quite some time now.
P.S: I'm also using butter knife.

Comment: How do you mean "`TextView` doesn't get update"?
Please explain what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have posted complete reference code and explanation. I have binded my textview with model and i'm setting text on model via binding instance but no effect.

Comment: Call `profilePayload.setFirstName` after `binding.setProfilePayload`. ButterKnife is IMHO not needed if using data binding.

Comment: You've missed to setVariable
binding.setVariable(BR.profilePayload, profilePayload);
Also you dn't need Butterknife ...

Comment: Followed https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html and they didn't call setVaraible too.

Comment: @ArtjomKönig did. still not working. Please see note that the binding is implemented inside a included layout not the actual activity. That's why i'm using the inflate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you're mixing data binding layouts with regular layouts.

If you want to include a data binding layout from a regular layout, you need to find the root view of the layout and call `bind()` on it. Maybe something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picker_dashboard);
    View bindingRoot = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    LayoutHeaderBinding binding = LayoutHeaderBinding.bind(bindingRoot);

    ProfileResponse.Payload profilePayload = new ProfileResponse.Payload();
    profilePayload.setFirstName("Test");

    binding.setProfilePayload(profilePayload);
}
```

However, it is better to make your Activity's layout a data binding layout and you won't have to do that extra work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="profilePayload"
            type="myms.models.ProfileResponse.Payload"/>
    </data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Top header -->

        <include layout="@layout/layout_header" app:profilePayload="@{profilePayload}" />

        <!-- DrawerLayout -->
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And then your binding code is much simpler and less error prone:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityPickerDashboardBinding binding = 
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_picker_dashboard);

    ProfileResponse.Payload profilePayload = new ProfileResponse.Payload();
    profilePayload.setFirstName("Test");

    binding.setProfilePayload(profilePayload);
}
```

On a different note, I think Android data binding and butterknife have significant overlap in functionality and I would recommend choosing one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Thanks George, it worked and also showing the simpler way. Can you please elaborate overlap in functionality. Is it error prone if i use both?

Comment: I wish that this step `View bindingRoot = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    LayoutHeaderBinding binding = LayoutHeaderBinding.bind(bindingRoot);` was added in the data binding official page examples section "includes"

Comment: Now i want to achieve something like this `android:text="hi, @{profilePayload.firstName} @{profilePayload.lastName}"` is it possible?

Comment: Yes, there are two ways. The best is to use string formatting: `"@{@string/hi(profilePayload.firstName)}"`. The other way is to use string concatenation: `'@{"hi, " + profilePayload.firstName}'`. When you use string constants, it is easier to use the single quotes(') for the attribute so you can use the double quotes inside the expression.

Comment: We don't recommend using the `findViewById()` way, so we don't advertise it. I'm pretty sure we do have something on using the `bind()` where you pass a View, though.

Comment: (I seem to be answering these in reverse order :-) I'm not too familiar with butterknife, so it would be good to hear an answer from someone more familiar with both. I don't know of any conflicts with using both, though. I *think* that both eliminate the need for `findViewById()` and they both have mechanisms for handling events like onClick.

Comment: Thanks geroge. Tried this `"@{@string/hi(profilePayload.firstName)}"` it only shows hi on screen (Really wished this technique would have work). Also how to concat variables using string formatting like `"@{@string/hi(profilePayload.firstName) (profilePayload.lastName}"` is it possible?

Comment: But butterknife doesn't have support for databinding. Also i like its other features so looking to keep both ;)

Comment: You must use a format string in your resources like `<string name="hello">hi %1$s %2$s</string>` to use an expression like `"@{@string/hello(user.firstName, user.lastName)}"`. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html and the resources section of https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot George, you are amazing.

Comment: now i wanted to do something like this android:text="@{profilePayload != null
        ? @string/hi_user(profilePayload.firstName, profilePayload.lastName)
        : ""}" but unable to use "" quotes inside the statement. Because initial the textview show Hi, null null.

Comment: You have two choices. Use single quotes around the whole attribute value or using back ticks for a string constant.

Comment: Thanks single quotes work :) Escaping with backslash doesn't :(

Comment: I meant the single back quote mark, like you use to indicate code in stack overflow.

Comment: Oh thanks i was using ' ' instead of `` and didn't know they are called back ticks. You are awesome George. Thanks for being very helpful. Hopefully see you soon at Google.

Comment: Found a bug in constraint layout. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879287/layout-messed-up-when-dialog-opens

Comment: Hey, can you please check why this is not working `android:visibility="@{(notificationResponse.payloads.size()) &lt; 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"` According the to the above statement the view should be hidden by default because initially `notificationResponse.payloads.size()` size will always be less than 1 but the is visible by default