# Layout messed up when dialog opens

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm facing a very strange bug with one of layout whose parent is ConstraintLayout. When ever a diaog is open the layout behind automatically start constracting and moving. Please refer attached gif for idea about the bug. Please check my code and see if i'm doing something wrong.

Here is my layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/picker_bg"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8dp">

    <!-- Pick details layout starts -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/load_details_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/load_status_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_12dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/load_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/load_id"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/stops"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/load_id_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="900"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/load_id"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/load_id"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/load_id" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stops"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/stops"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/truck"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/load_id" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stops_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/stops"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/stops"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stops" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/truck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/truck"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/trailer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/stops" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/truck_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="100"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/truck"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/truck"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/truck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trailer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/trailer"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/truck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trailer_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="300"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/trailer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/trailer"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trailer" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Pick details layout end -->

    <!-- Pick status layout starts -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/load_status_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_move_items_to_stage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/load_details_card">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_12dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/start_time"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Start"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/status"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/status"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/status" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/start_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Start Time"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/break_time"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/status" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/start_time_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="472423"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/start_time"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/start_time"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/start_time"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="355dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/break_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Break Time"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/total_breaks"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/start_time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/break_time_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="00:00:00"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/break_time"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/break_time"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/break_time"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1154dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_breaks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Total Breaks"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/break_time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_breaks_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/total_breaks"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/total_breaks"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/total_breaks" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Pick status layout end -->

    <!-- Button move items to stage -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_unload_items"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_archive_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_4dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:tag="picking"
        android:text="@string/unload_items"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/load_status_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_finish_loading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/load_status_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/load_status_card"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <!-- Button finish picking -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_finish_loading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:text="Finish Loading"
        android:textColor="@color/white"

        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_unload_items"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_unload_items"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bt_unload_items"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <!-- Button instructions -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_instructions"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_53dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/layout_progress"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/load_details_card" />

    <!-- Picking progress layout-->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_progress"
        layout="@layout/layout_progress_horizontal_percentage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_instructions"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_suspend"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_instructions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bt_instructions" />

    <!-- Button suspend -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_suspend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_stop_black_24dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:text="Suspend"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_progress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_pause"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/layout_progress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_progress"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="654dp" />

    <!-- Button pause -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_pause"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_pause_black_24dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_suspend"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_suspend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bt_suspend"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1089dp" />

    <!-- Building selection layout starts -->

    <!-- Building selection layout ends -->

    <!-- Fragment Container -->
    <!-- app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_building" -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_nested_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/layout_stop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_instructions">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nested_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/layout_stop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scrollview_nested_fragment_container"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_instructions"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/all_stops"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/selector_building_bg"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
                android:tag="0">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="All"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/all_stops_pick_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/selector_building_arrow" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/stop_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/selector_building_bg"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
                android:tag="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Stop 1"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stop_1_pick_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/selector_building_arrow" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/stop_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/selector_building_bg"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
                android:tag="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Stop 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stop_2_pick_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/selector_building_arrow" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/stop_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/selector_building_bg"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
                android:tag="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Stop 3"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stop_3_pick_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_building_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/selector_building_arrow" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Table layout -->

    <!-- <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:id="@+id/table"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/layout_building"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_instructions"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_building">

         <include layout="@layout/layout_picking_table" />

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the gif
[image]

Comment: I faced this bug multiple times too. Has it been reported?

Comment: Going to report it to the guys who are presenting this years I/O about ConstraintLayout.

Comment: But I don't know if the bug is really with the ConstraintLayout, because it only happened to me when I wrote the layout by XML, and I was a bit inexperienced. When I started using the design editor, I stopped happening.